# How to make a function that creates a file counting how much the operation is used?

Tags: python-3.x, function

I want to make a function that creates a file counting how much the operation is used.

Essentially, if the function is ran the first time, the file is created and in the file there is a number placed 1. Additionally, when the program is ran the next time, in that already created file adds +1, so it changes to 2.
This is done in Python. Any ideas on how to script that?

I have tried this is java and it worked but I have problems getting the proper syntax in python 3. Help would be very appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will do the trick

```py
import os
COUNTER_PATH = './count'

def operation_counter():
  if os.path.exists(COUNTER_PATH):
    with open(COUNTER_PATH, 'r+') as f:
      count = int(f.read())
      f.seek(0)
      count += 1
      f.write(str(count))
      f.truncate()
  else:
    with open(COUNTER_PATH, 'w') as f:
      f.write('1')
```